# Multiple assemblies from one maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

we have different java source code "projects". 3 projects are completly identical(fatclient, same dependencies etc.) - there is only another main class that have to be invoked.

Today we have one base-project with a main class:

```
<project>
    <groupId>net.company.BaseTool</groupId>
    <artifactId>BaseTool</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BaseTool</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>net.company.BaseTool</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and other projects that depending on the base-project

```
<project>
    <groupId>net.company.AnotherTool</groupId>
    <artifactId>AnotherTool</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>AnotherTool</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>net.company.AnotherTool</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.company.BaseTool</groupId>
            <artifactId>BaseTool</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

We are doing this, because we need simple double-click startable applications.

But I dont want to create an extra java project for each application.

My question is: **Is it possible to create multiple assemblies from one project?** And if yes, how it should be done.

**Here comes the solution**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.company.toolbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>toolbox</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>toolbox</name>
    <url>http://wiki.company.my/toolbox</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>toolbox</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ToolOne</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>ToolOne</finalName>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>my.company.ToolOne</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ToolTwo</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>ToolTwo</finalName>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>my.company.ToolTwo</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ToolThree</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>ToolThree</finalName>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>my.company.ToolThree</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ToolFour</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>ToolFour</finalName>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>my.company.ToolFour</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Please use a more up-to-date version of the maven-assembly-plugin. The [current up-to-date version](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|maven-assembly-plugin) is 2.4.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [different executions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) of the assembly plugin and then [attach the resulting assembly](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) to the build. Of course you have to configure different final names for the artifacts in the assembly plugin configuration.

Comment: Cool! It looks like this, what I'm looking for! So I'll check it out tomorrow! I'll give you feedback than! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mirko can you upload the final pom.xml as a example?? Thnks!!

Comment: [attach-artifact new link](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) following Codehaus moved to MojoHaus.

Comment: @Gurvan Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: Different final named and also different execution ids.

Comment: For an example see the question this one duplicates, or https://gist.github.com/KlausBrunner/9954309